# Compare order of rownames between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two large data frames. I want to compare whether the order of rows are the same between the two data frames. IS there a way of doing this in R?

Comment: It is not clear what you want without providing an example.

Answer (score -1):

Below R code will give you comparision of two data.frames by rownames.

```
table(rownames(df1) == rownames(df2))
```

If you need to compare any column than expose column name by $ operator as below

```
table(rownames(df1$mycol) == rownames(df2$mycol))
```